# JSON Object always return undefined with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

The JSON Object always return undefined in spite of the object contains data, i check it by using breakpoints in debugging

This is Action method in Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetMoreComments(int CommsCount, int ArticleID)
{
    List<ComViewModel> comms = articleService.GetMoreComments(ArticleID, CommsCount);
    return Json( comms );
}
```

and I also replaced the code in Action method to simple code like that but not work too:

```
public JsonResult GetMoreComments(int CommsCount, int ArticleID)
{
    ComViewModel com = new ComViewModel
        {
            CommentContent = "cooooooooooontent",
            CommentID = 99,
            SpamCount = 22
        };
    return Json( com );
}
```

This is jQuery code for AJAX:

```
function GetMoreComments() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: { CommsCount: @Model.Comments.Count, ArticleID: @Model.ArticleID },
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMoreComments", "Comment")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

            var JsonParseData = JSON.parse(result);
            alert(JsonParseData[0].CommentID)
            alert(result[0].CommentID);
            alert(result[0]["CommentID"]);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I believe you have to "echo" or print the response not return it.

Comment: @RobertRocha this ain't php

Comment: it is asp.net core mvc

Comment: mind putting what is inside `result` in success callback

Comment: Like masterpreenz said, check your response in the developer tools.

Comment: Also alert(result) not the way you have it since its not parsed yet.

Comment: i parse it and not work, i update my question

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would have to parse your data if you need to alert it the way you have it. alert(result) should show data. If you need to access array of objects you must parse it first. Here is my example....

```
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);

    //PARSE data if you need to access objects
    var resultstring = response.replace(',]',']');
    var JsonParseData = JSON.parse(resultstring);

    alert(JsonParseData[0].address)

    });
```

That is wordpress ajax but its the same concept

Comment: not succeed, i parse it before too, when use parsing alert not appear yet!!

Comment: Have you just tried alert(result)? If that doesnt work then it could be a server side issue.

Comment: yes i tried, it give me [object, object],[object, object],[object, object] ..... and repeat to number of list count

Comment: Ok print out your result to the console then screen shot the picture in your debugger. Like this....
console.log(result);